# application config settings for facebook/twitter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I have been following the solution provided in a previous question:

[Accessing config from application.rb in Controller (Rails 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143638/accessing-config-from-application-rb-in-controller-rails-3/4145499#4145499)

but applying it for Facebook settings first.

I created the facebook config file first:

```
#lib/facebook_config.rb
module FacebookConfig
  def self.config
    @@config ||= {}
  end

  def self.config=(hash)
    @@config = hash
  end
```

end

and defined my YAML file then initialised it.

```
#config/facebook.yml
development:
  app_id = "id"
  app_secret = "secret"

test:
  app_id = "id"
  app_secret = "secret"

production:
  app_id = "id"
  app_secret = "secret"
```

and

```
#config/intializers/01.facebook_config.rb
require './lib/facebook_config'

FacebookConfig.config = YAML.load_file("config/facebook.yml")[Rails.env]
```

and defining the omniauth config as such:

```
#config/initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  # The following is for facebook
  provider :facebook, FacebookConfig.config[:app_id], FacebookConfig.config[:app_secret], {:scope => 'email, read_stream, read_friendlists, friends_likes, friends_status, offline_access'}
end
```

however when I am testing in development mode I get the following error when starting up the webrick server:

config/initializers/omniauth.rb:3:in `[]': can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError)

I thought when accessing the config file it should be a String and not a Symbol?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Using Rails 3.2 with Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reason could be because of your facebook.yml file formatting.

You can read about Yaml here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML

## Edited

I have tested your code in dummy app - same error, because, YAML file you have currently, will return string.

```
1.9.3p0 :014 > YAML.load_file("config/facebook.yml")[Rails.env]
 => "app_id = \"id\" app_secret = \"secret\""
```

So you can not access by `symbol`, because Ruby thinks that you are passing `Numeric Index` value for `String`.

Update your facebook.yml to this one (set your variables):

```
#config/facebook.yml
development:
  app_id: id
  app_secret: secret

test:
  app_id: id
  app_secret: secret

production:
  app_id: id
  app_secret: secret
```

After facebook.yml update, as result you will get hash:

```
YAML.load_file("config/facebook.yml")[Rails.env]
 => {"app_id"=>"id", "app_secret"=>"secret"}
```

Symbolize your config hash keys:

```
  def self.config=(hash)
    @@config = hash
    @@config.symbolize_keys!
  end
```

And it will work!

Comment: I tried this and still have the same error when booting up the webrick server.

I tested the YAML file and it is valid YAML on http://yamllint.com/

Comment: Thanks for this. Seems to work now as your first answer was correct. The format of my YAML was converting it to strings.

Comment: by the way it was the fact that I left out the colon in the YAML file that was converting the details into a string and not a hash.