# Update rails config file from Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, app-config

I have a app running on rails, that loads config from a yaml file.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to update this from a controller, or should I be using a ActiveModel for my config?

The configuration is based on the answer here:
[Accessing config from application.rb in Controller (Rails 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143638/accessing-config-from-application-rb-in-controller-rails-3])

config/my_app_config.yaml contains the configuration.

An initializer in config/initializerz/app_config.rb loads this:

AppConfig.config = YAML.load_file("config/my_app_config.yaml")[Rails.env].symbolize_keys

I can easily access this config from a controller and display it in a view by accessing MyAppConfig.config[:key_name], and update it from user input, but is there a recommended way to write the config hash back to the config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO it's should be avoided. If nature of your config is dynamic (changes in time) then you should just read it from DB as you read User data or whatever.
If it's static then you may keep it in hash (YAML file, when config changes you just deploy your app). If settings change frequently I would recommend db.